# How to add an initial/default value using Django Filters?

Tags: python, django

How can I add an initial/default value when using [Django Filters](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter)?

For example, something like this `initial=False`

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    archive = django_filters.BooleanFilter(initial=False)

    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ['archive']
```

I've tired to override the `__init__` but this does not appear to work.

Comment: What about applying default filters to the initial queryset of the view?

Comment: @serg seems to be overwritten at some point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try overriding the `__init__` method of `UserFilter`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.form.initial['archive'] = False
```

Comment: Sorry, I should added, I've using DRF and filters are applied over the request.

Answer (score 10):

For DRF you can try override `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['data']._mutable = True
    if 'archive' not in kwargs['data']:
        kwargs['data']['archive'] = False
    kwargs['data']._mutable = False
    super(UserFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But you should read [django-filter.readthedocs.io...using-initial-values-as-defaults](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/main/guide/tips.html#using-initial-values-as-defaults)

Comment: It's worth nothing that this is not recommended ,as per the link above. You shouldn't set default/initial values

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in that I wanted to preserve the users selections even after they had navigated away from the page.  I implemented my solution in the Filter View as follows...

```
class BucketLookupView(UserPassesTestMixin,SingleTableMixin,FilterView):
    template_name = "finance/planning-bucket-lookup.html"
    model = finance_models.SalesOrderBucket
    filterset_class = finance_filters.BucketFilter
    table_class = finance_tables.BucketTable

    def get_filterset_kwargs(self,*args):
        kwargs = super().get_filterset_kwargs(*args)
        if kwargs['data']:
            bucket_filter_data = kwargs['data']
            self.request.session['bucket_filter_data']= bucket_filter_data
        else:
            if 'bucket_filter_data' in self.request.session.keys():
                kwargs['data']=self.request.session['bucket_filter_data']
        return kwargs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approximate code snippet I used:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    filters = QueryDict('is_archive=true', mutable=True)
    filters.update(request.GET)
```

You build a new QueryDict as request.GET is immutable. Not that efficient, but looks pretty to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a remix of @IlyaPetukhov's answer that I find easier to read:

```py
def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if data is not None:
        data = data.copy()
        data.setdefault("archive", False)  
    super(UserFilter, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you're uncomfortable with `data = data.copy()`, you can replace it with `data._mutable = True`; just know that it's not officially supported by Django.

Answer (score 0):

form.cleaned_data is using to add filters to the queryset and no initial value is set for cleaned data.
The solution could be to override form property:

```
@property
def form(self) -> ModelForm:
    form = super().form
    form.data = form.data.copy()
    form.data.setdefault("archive", False)
    return form
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading [django-filter warnings](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tips.html?highlight=initial#using-initial-values-as-defaults), I opted to redirect if filter is not set:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

class EntrepriseList(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = EntrepriseTable
    model = Entreprise
    template_name = 'stage/entreprise_list.html'
    filterset_class = EntrepriseFilter
    paginate_by = 30


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
            qd['archive'] = False
            urlnext = reverse('current_page_name') # or just url from request
            urlnext += f'?{qd.urlencode()}'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlnext)
```