# How do you set a default value for django-filter select field instead of a blank field?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using the `django-filter`app to filter items on my front end and i can't seem to understand how to populate the first value on my dropdown select field with a default value instead of the blank `--------` space on the field, its really bad for user experience since im not using labels and therefore users wont be able to identify a field without a placeholder of some sort. Here is what i'm getting.

[image]

Comment: look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833494/how-to-add-an-initial-default-value-using-django-filters) a question with an answer similar to yours

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an initial/default value using Django Filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833494/how-to-add-an-initial-default-value-using-django-filters)

Comment: still doesn't work for me, i'm thinking this is a django-filter app problem since my model fields on my admin work just fine and have no space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By creating a class for the filter and inherit from filter set and use the empty_label propriety like below example:

filter class:

```
class StudentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    student__nationality = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Nationality.objects.all(), empty_label=('Nationality'))

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = {
            'student__nationality': ['exact'],
        }
```

In view only use this command:

```
model = Student
filterset_class = StudentFilter
```

for more information, check (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filterset.html)

Comment: Using "empty_label=" is the right solution - thanks. However, I suspect that including the fields dict in class Meta is not, or is no longer appropriate (in Django_filter 21 or 22). It failed for me, and the documentation suggests that it should indeed be avoided: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html (form which: "Including declarative aliases in a fields dict will raise an error" - and indeed, it does :-).

Answer (score 0):

Is possible do it too in settings.py

```
FILTERS_EMPTY_CHOICE_LABEL = 'some label'
```